# Finding confidence score for ensuring probability of current location

Tags: java, algorithm, date, statistics

**Context:** Database table "MobileLocations" contains latitude, longitude and timestamp. To predict current address by analyzing latitude, longitude and time,I need to check if corresponding dates are consecutive dates for latitude and longitude.

**Problem:**
Have to find a algo where dates can be either consecutive days or if not consecutive one/two days gap occasionally should also do.For example, if I am analyzing 15 days night location data for a person, he may not be at home for one or two days. 
My thought is,

```
public boolean consecutiveDates(Date date1, Date date2){
       int confidenceScore=0;
      if(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(date1.getTime()-date2.getTime())<90000){//almost 24 hours difference, so consecutive dates
              //confidenceScore is maximum
    else {
    //more the gap, less the confidence score, and if gap is like 5 days, confidence score is zero
}

return (confidenceScore>70?true:false)
}
```

Need a second opinion, if it makes sense. Not sure how to calculate confidenceScore. Else what cloud be best possible option to achieve the same?